# i have created the guessing game in python but it's giving an index error

Tags: python, index-error

```
from random import randint

import sys

answer = randint(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))

while True:
    try:
        guess = int(input(f'guess a number {sys.argv[1]}~{sys.argv[2]}:  '))
        if 0 < guess < 11:
            if guess == answer:
                print('you are a genius!')
                break
        else:
            print('hey bozo, I said 1~10')
    except ValueError:
        print('please enter a number')
        continue
```

But it's giving an index error on line 5! what to do

Comment: how did you run the program, most likely you provided less number of arguments that required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing enought parameters. You should check the lenght of argv before access to their positions:

```py
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
   print(f'Not enought params usage: {sys.argv[0]} min_value max_value')
   exit(-1)
```

Comment: i don't understand can you be precise ??

Comment: It seems that you are running your code with incorrect arguments. You need to run something like: `python my_program 1 10`